# Automating Instagram posts with Python: How to use the Instagram API provided by Facebook developers?

Tags: python, api, automation, instagram

I've set up an app on https://developers.facebook.com/ and got my access token when setting a testing user but I'm confused on how would I be able to use it with requests library in order to post on my page. As of now, I'm just using instagrapi library but it has some drawbacks as it requires me to input my 2fa code everytime I need to log in.

That's why I need to use my access token instead which solves that issue but I don't know how nor have I seen any others explain it.

This is the current code:

```
import os
import requests
import instagrapi
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

username = "user"
password = "pass"

client_id = os.getenv("INSTAGRAM_APP_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("INSTAGRAM_SECRET")
access_token = os.getenv("INSTAGRAM_TOKEN")

media_file = "C:/Users/Stella/Pictures/00011.jpg"
caption = "Test!"

graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/"

api = instagrapi.Client()
api.login(username=username, password=password)

user_id = api.user_id_from_username("testname")


def post(post_text, image_path):
    api.photo_upload(image_path, post_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    post(caption, media_file)
```

I've tried looking at the official documentation but they seem too confusing in terms of permssions and stuff.

Comment: What do you want, how does this not work?

Comment: I don't wanna log in using my credentials but using the access token instead that is provided by the instagram basic display app